# SQL - Find all words that start with some phrase

Tags: mysql, sql, search, substring, sql-like

I have many books in my MySQL database. And I am looking for a specific words in my book headers. For example, I can find every header begins with the word "dan":

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE header LIKE 'dan%';
```

But how to find a word inside the header that begins with the certain phrase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty trick: A word begins with `dan` can either be at the beginning of a `header` or after a space, so:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE header LIKE 'dan%' OR header like '% dan%';
```

Comment: Why not use `trim()` first and then `like`?cause `header like '% dan%'` logically means word `dan` can appear anywhere in header and not necessarily at beginning.

Comment: @Rahul because I'm trying to avoid having to split the header into separate words. How would you use `trim` to handle a header like `Rahul and dan are browsing StackOverflow`?. The space before dan in `'% dan%'` verifies it's the beginning of a **word**.

Comment: Make sense .. Ah!! I got it now. OP has framed the question wrongly. It should have been `check if dan is a separate word` +1

Answer (score 2):

A slight simplification is the following logic, which puts a space at the beginning of the header:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE ' ' || header LIKE ' dan%';
```

The only issue is that concatenating the string depends on the database and the question doesn't mention the database.  So it might also be:

```
WHERE ' ' + header LIKE ' dan%';
```

or

```
WHERE CONCAT(' ', header) LIKE ' dan%';
```